# Why does the default ASP.NET MVC 3 project not use controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Upon creating a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor site, there are 9 Account\*.cshtml files which seem to be views with the controller logic inserted at the top of the view in an anonymous code block. There is no account controller class.

Why is this? As I understood, the benefit of MVC was the separation of concerns of code & presentation. Does this imply that I should remove all of the existing files & re-implement the Authentication & Authorisation layers?

It seems odd that MS would ship the 'worst possible example' with their flagship web framework.

Thanks,
Jarrod

**Edit: I was using the wrong entry point within visual studio to create the application (see my comment below). Thanks!**

Comment: I'm using VS express and have the same setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect. Here's the default folder structure in the MVC3 Razor starter app:

[image]

As you can see, there are two controllers in the ~/Controllers folder.

Just to be clear, I started a new VS2010 instance, created a new MVC3 project, selected "Internet Application" and Razor as the view engine.

Comment: Thank you! I was using the wrong entry point for creating the application, and I wasn't offered the variant you showed there. What I was creating was the via the File > New > Website > ASP.NET Website (Razor), which is not correct (nor is actually MVC).

Comment: Yeah, it as to be a Web Application **Project**, not a website. Projects are precompiled, while websites are on the wrong end of obsolete. You can use the Razor view engine in any type of application (even non-web apps), but you should create an MVC web application to use the MVC infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, something is not quite right on your end.
I just created a new ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application.
I do have a 'Controllers' folder with a proper AccountController as part of the project.

Are you using Visual Studio?